# Enabling HTTP2 for Spring Boot with Istio microservices

Tags: spring-boot, istio, http2

We are planning to enable HTTP2 for microservice communication in a Kubernetes cluster. This microservices are built with Spring Boot 3.

Since HTTP2 requires HTTPS, the problem we wanted to avoid was configuring TLS on every Spring Boot application. Initially we thought of taking advantage of Istio's sidecar mTLS and enable HTTP2 directly there, making it transparent to the Spring Boot applications.

With it in place the communication would be:

```
MICROSERVICE1 ---[HTTPS(mTLS)-HTTP2]---> MICROSERVICE2(ISTIO SIDECAR CONTAINER ---[HTTP-HTTP1.1]---> SPRING BOOT)
```

Since the whole communication pipeline is not fully HTTP2, I'm not sure this would be enough or we would have to enable HTTP2 Spring Boot's side using `server.http2.enabled=true` and configure TLS.

Is there any way to enable HTTP2 transparently for the existing applications o there's no other way than configuring TLS directly on them?

Comment: HTTP/2 does not require TLS. Only browsers require TLS for HTTP/2. On backend systems you can typically use clear-text HTTP/2 (unless you have other requirements of confidentiality) to communicate among nodes.

Answer (score 0):

**For Using mTLS:**

As you mentioned by adopting istio service mesh, Application / Micro Services need not to have any configuration w.r.t mTLS.  Istio will enable mTLS communication between pods.  For pod to pod mTLS communication following will be the high level flow.

> Microservice container1 <--- http ---> IstioProxySidecar <--- https
> ---> IstioProxySidecar <--- http ---> Microservice container2.

To enable mTLS an PeerAuthentication, DestinationRule objects have to be created. For more details [mTLS istio documentation](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/security/authentication/mtls-migration/#lock-down-to-mutual-tls-by-namespace) can be referred.

**For Using HTTP2:**

Usually istio does automatic protocol selection.  If it needs to specifically done this can be achieved using below options.  For more details [istio documentation](https://istio.io/latest/docs/ops/configuration/traffic-management/protocol-selection/#explicit-protocol-selection) can be referred

- By the name of the port: name: [-].
- By the appProtocol field: appProtocol: .

Both mTLS and http2 are separate and can be utilized respectively.